# Press And Hold for 1 Second

Tags: android, touch

How To **Get Time** For **Press And Hold** Button Or EditText
For Example When User Press And Hold EditText For "**1 Second**", It Show Toast. So Not Before
I Watched Some Questions But I Don't Understand Them Or Wasn't Useful To Me

Android 2.2

Eclipse

Comment: Does [onLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) not work for you?

Comment: If it doesn't, record a time stamp in the event method which received presses and compare it to one in that which receives releases, and decide if the interval was as long as you want.  But if you do that, make sure you code doesn't error or get in an unrecoverable state as a result of movements onto or off the button while depressed.